# alternative to call dispatch from a exported function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting the error

React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "move" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

I have a component boardSquare which imports and calls handleMove

```
import { handleMove } from './Game'

export default function BoardSquare({ piece, black, position,isFromSquare,isToSquare}) {

 handleMove(value)

}
```

and inside inside game.js which holds handleMove

there is also imports chess.js which provides a string value

```
//game.js

import * as Chess from 'chess.js'

const chess = new Chess()



export function handleMove() {


const chessFen = chess.fen()
  
const dispatch = useDispatch();

                dispatch(setFen(chess.fen()))

}
```

obviously i can't call dispatch there though i need an alternative as eventually i want to do the following

which is

inside Gameapp.js

have

```
function GameApp() {

const fen = useSelector(state => state.fen) 

  const [board, setBoard] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {  
setBoard(fen
}, [fen])

}
 
return (
<Board board={board} 
         />
)
```

because i want to update Board with the fen value when it is called in game.js

Answer (score 0):

You can get the function dispatch in your component BoardSquare and use it as a callback to handleMove :

```
export default function BoardSquare({ piece, black, position,isFromSquare,isToSquare}) {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 
 return <div onClick={(value) => handleMove(value, dispatch)}/>
}

function handleMove(dispatchFunction) {
 const chessFen = chess.fen()
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 dispatchFunction(setFen(chess.fen()))
}
```

You could also return the value to dispatch from handlemove and dispatch it in your component, which might look cleaner and be easier to test

```
export default function BoardSquare({ piece, black, position,isFromSquare,isToSquare}) {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 

 return <div onClick={(value) => dispatch(handleMove(value))}/>
}

function handleMove(value) {
 const chessFen = chess.fen()
 return setFen(chess.fen())
}
```

As an aside, please try to make your code more coherent/readable when looking for help, you probably tried to be succint, but your component BoardSquare doesn't make sense as you wrote it in your question, handlemove is given a value not present in its signature, and the indentation is off

Comment: thanks, asking the question is easier said than done tried my best ,

Answer (score 0):

I just made another function called getFen()       and did it like so

```
export function getFen(){
return chess.fen()
}

import getFen()

handlemove(){
fen = getFen()
dispatch(setFen(fen)
}
```